# Haskell Polymorphic definition

Tags: haskell

I am unable to understand the difference between `fold` and `foldr`.
The definition of `fold` is:

```
fold :: (t->t->t) -> [t] -> t
fold f [a]    = a
fold f (a:b:x)= f a (fold f (b:x))
```

where there is only one type-parameter `t`

`foldr` is defined as

```
foldr :: (t->u->u) -> u -> [t] -> u
foldr f s []    = s
foldr f s (a:x) = f a (foldr f s x)
```

I am reading "The craft of functional programming" and it says the `fold` function is modified by adding an extra argument for the purpose of checking for empty list. This doesn't make sense why there was a need for `foldr` when the `fold` function itself could have been modified to serve all the purposes.

Secondly,when I tried the following example from the book:

```
rev :: [t] -> [t]
rev list = foldr stick [] list

stick :: t -> [t] -> [t]
stick a x = x++[a]
```

and modified the definition of `foldr` to `foldr::(t->t->t)->[t]->t`. Hugs threw an error of inifinite unification type. I tried googling but could not find a satisfactory answer.

so to sum up my doubts are as follows:

- doubt1: The reason for making the `foldr` types to be more general than fold.
- doubt2: why do i get an error namely infinitely unification type.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Notice `fold` is not some universal function in Haskell so your question is actually incomplete.  Please put in some effort next time.

Comment: @PatrickCollins which is no problem at all here...

Comment: @Carsten no problem if OP puts in some significant work.

Comment: i had rephrased the question

Comment: if you modify `fold` the way you hinted you will end up with `foldr` - on GHC(i) your `rev` definition is fine and works as expected - so either you ran in yet another Hugs bug or you missed something - please consider using GHC instead of Hugs even if you do the FP101x course - if you have trouble use Hugs for the "*copy&past into your REPL to get the type*" questions - for the rest GHC is just the *saner* option

Comment: ...oops now I get it ... of course you **should not** use the **all** `t` version of `foldr` for `rev` (how did you even get this to compile?) - in the `(t -> t -> t) -> [t] -> t`: just look at `stick` - if you want to *stick* `stick` into your `fold` then `t` needs to be both `t` and `[t]` just from it's type

Answer (score 2):

I'll start at the end:

```
rev :: [t] -> [t]
rev list = foldr stick [] list

stick :: t -> [t] -> [t]
stick a x = x ++ [a]
```

will work just fine if you use the definition of `foldr` you gave:

```
foldr :: (t->u->u) -> u -> [t] -> u
foldr f s []    = s
foldr f s (a:x) = f a (foldr f s x)
```

as you can see here:

```
λ> rev [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

what will not work is if you replace it with your definition of `fold`:

```
fold :: (t->t->t) -> [t] -> t
```

no matter how you name it because the trouble start with the signature.

See - when you do `rev list = fold stick [] list` then you say that

```
t -> t -> t
```

should somehow be equal to

```
t' -> [t'] -> [t']
```

as the first one is the type `fold` expects for it's first *argument* and the second is the signature given by `stick` (renamed `t` to `t'` here to indicate that the types should could be different).

Now this would mean that both `t ~ t'` and `t ~ [t']` or `t ~ [t]` which is most likely the error you get (btw: `a ~ b` here is me saying *two types `a` and `b`  should be equal* - think `=` if you like)

This should shed some light on your **doubt2** I hope

---

now to the first part: To be honest I have no clue what I should tell you.

The reason to make `fold` more general is that then it's *more general* - indeed `foldr` is a very special function for lists - it is [the list catamorphism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Catamorphisms) (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism#List_fold))

But that's just *complicated* for *general function to operate on lists*

Indeed you can rewrite a huge number of functions on list (basically the recursive ones using patter-matching in the *empty or cons* style) with just `foldr` - and this will very likely be a big part of your course (I think you are a student of FP101x right?) and of your book - as it's **the example** for higher-order-functions *to rule them all* ;)

Comment: i am not a student of FP 101x.I picked up this book from the library and trying to learn haskell.

Comment: @user3274335 oh sorry - it's just that almost all (you are the first exception I see) people using Hugs in the last days came from there - just move to GHC then